# Use random userAgent for Selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, user-agent, selenium-firefoxdriver

Need use random userAgent. My code it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

# init Profile options for navigation
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

# Set userAgent
fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "custom userAgent")
fp.update_preferences()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally use the [fake-useragent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent/) library.

You can generate random useragents with:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("general.useragent.override", UserAgent().random)
fp.update_preferences()
```